# I am getting error in creating App Bundle in Android: uses reserved file or directory name 'res'

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am trying to create app bundle in native Android application and getting following error

Execution failed for task ':app:packageDEVreleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
> File 'root/res/drawable-anydpi-v24/<>.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.

Earlier issue was occuring for AndroidManifest.xml file, I have used

```
packagingOptions {
        //pickFirst '**/*.so'
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86_64/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/mips/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/mips64/*.so"
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
```

If I exclude anydpi folder then it starts giving error in hdpi folder and keep on, in the end it also starts giving error in layout files which shows that problem area is something else.

Comment: There is no issue coming in creating apk file, problem is only with bundle creation

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in one of custom Android library project which we had created. Android was showing incorrect error. In Android library project, we had added one another custom android library as aar file. Same custom library was added in all other library project and application project as Maven dependency. After removing aar file and using maven dependency, problem got fixed.